# Segmentation error on string affectation within a tagged union

Tags: c++, unions, stdstring

I have the following simplified code that models a Variable that can be an integer or a string:

```
//tagged union
union VariableValueType {
    std::int64_t  i;
    std::string   s;

    VariableValueType(void): i(0) {}
    ~VariableValueType(void) {}
};
enum class VariableType {Undefined, Integer, String};

class Variable
{
    VariableValueType _value;
    VariableType _type;

    //constructor from a string
    Variable(const VariableType type, const std::string& value)
     : _type(VariableType::Undefined)
    {
        set(type,value);
    }

    // setter
    void set(const VariableType type, const std::string& value)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case VariableType::Integer :
                _value.i = std::stoi(value);
                _type = VariableType::Integer;
                break;
            case VariableType::String :
                _value.s = value; //<-- crashes here!!!
                _type = VariableType::String;
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

When I call `set` from another point in the code with `type=String`, I get a segmentation fault on the string affectation line.

```
#0  0x00007ffff7b70c73 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7b70f89 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00005555556c3fdd in Variable::set (this=0x5555559d7ae0, type=VariableType::String, value="1") at /home/.../Variable.cpp:118
```

I can't figure what is going on here...

Fun fact: if I add `std::string foo = value;` as the first line of the `set` method, then the segmentation fault disapears...

---

**Edit**:

When I ask gdb the value of `_value.s`, I get the following message:

```
error reading variable: Cannot create a lazy string with address 0x0, and a non-zero length.
```

Which I do not understand...

Comment: My money is on you invoking **Undefined Behavior**. Unfortunately, "you cannot simply" change the active member of a union to another member of a non-trivial type. You have to use *placement new* to construct and destruct appropriately. There's alot of interesting stuff to learn about object-lifetimes in C++. :-)

Comment: Arf, I used it in the copy constructor (not showed here) but forgot it in the affectation in `set` function. Silly me...

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a string in a union. Don't use anything with an object that is not POD ( so with a constructor/destructor) in a union.

The reason is that your constructor will not get called, which means that the object will have an undefined state.

Use a `std::variant` instead (or `boost::variant` if you don't have C++17).

Comment: "Don't use anything with an object that is not POD (so with a constructor/destructor) in a union." why?

Comment: Yes, its good to suggest the right way; But also know that sometimes, some people want to learn by trying. And want to understand why something failed... So, a little explanation to the OP will be more educative than "Don't do XYZ"

Comment: C++11 (unlike previous C++) is fine with unions containing these types. It's not a particularly great idea to rush to use them, but it's legal.

Comment: Actually, I know `xxx::variant` exists, but to the best of my knowledge, only in C++17, which I can't rely on. I i'd like, if possible, not having to include the whole Boost library just for this.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Agreed, but there are steps in the learning. When you are a beginner, writing your own type-safe variant is not easy. It's not for experts either.

Comment: @Silverspur in that case, you want to use placement new and delete to construct and delete your objects properly (AFAIK).

Comment: Arf, I used it in the copy constructor (not showed here) but forgot it in the affectation in `set` function. Silly me...

Comment: @chris In that case you still at least need some placement new to construct the object when switching active members. It very quickly becomes a mess and this is why we shall use `variant` instead to manage the mess for us.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher As fas as the deletion is concerned, must I add a `_value.s.~std::string()` before the affectation?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yeah, it's not the simplest part of the language for sure.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments and the other answer, the problem comes from the fact that union elements that are not POD cannot be simply intialized: a placement new should be used instead. One must also take care, when using such unions, to delete non-POD elements when they are not used anymore.

Here, it would go like:

```
// before assigning something else than a string
if(_type == VariableType::String) _value.s.~std::string();

// to assign a string if current type is *not* a string
new(&_value.s) std::string(value);
// to assign a string if current type is a string
_value.s = value;
```

It has also been mentioned that such unions with non-POD elements can be more easily handled with dedicated libraries:

- Directly available in C++17 as `std::variant`
- Available via Boost as `boost::variant`
- Available via mapbox/variant (Boost alternative: lighter library)

Comment: Don't forget to explicitly call the string's destructor when needed.

Comment: Why are you destroying the string when it's a string you want to create? That makes no sense. You'd just keep using the string that is already there.

Comment: These were not supposed to be two consecutive lines of code, but this was indeed quite confusing. I've updated the answer.